# Is there an alternative to EXTRACTVALUE function in MySql 5.0

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-5.0

I am using **MySql 5.0** in the servers. Some functionality implemented using **MySql 5.1** in development environments are not working in production servers. One such function is `EXTRACTVALUE` function used to extract values in XML data.

Hope someone might have done previously to extract XML values in a MySql 5.0. Really appreciate if share the implemented MySql function that work like `EXTRACTVALUE` or the idea how to do that.

Comment: What stops you from upgrading to 5.1 or 5.5? Otherwise, you will have to reinvent the wheel, or not use XML at all - it does not belong to database anyway.

Comment: Hi @mvp, management approval is required for server upgrades and it'll take some time. Can not delay the functionality updates until then.